# Override DependencyInjection or unload XML/YML

Tags: php, symfony

I have mybundle to override SonataMediaBundle,

So,this is my bundle

Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\DependencyInjection\ApplicationSonataMediaExtension

```
class ApplicationSonataMediaExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
           $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));  
        $loader->load('myservice.xml'); 
    }
```

and this is original DependancyInjection.
Sonata\MediaBundle\DependencyInjection\SonataMediaExtension

```
  class SonataMediaExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $processor = new Processor();
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('provider.xml');
        $loader->load('media.xml');
        $loader->load('twig.xml');
        $loader->load('security.xml');
        $loader->load('extra.xml');
        $loader->load('form.xml');
        $loader->load('gaufrette.xml');

        // NEXT_MAJOR: Remove Following lines
        $amazonS3Definition = $container->getDefinition('sonata.media.adapter.service.s3');
        if (method_exists($amazonS3Definition, 'setFactory')) {
            $amazonS3Definition->setFactory(array('Aws\S3\S3Client', 'factory'));
        } else {
            $amazonS3Definition->setFactoryClass('Aws\S3\S3Client');
            $amazonS3Definition->setFactoryMethod('factory');
        }

        // NEXT_MAJOR: Remove Following lines
        $openCloudDefinition = $container->getDefinition('sonata.media.adapter.filesystem.opencloud.objectstore');
        if (method_exists($openCloudDefinition, 'setFactory')) {
            $openCloudDefinition->setFactory(array(new Reference('sonata.media.adapter.filesystem.opencloud.connection'), 'ObjectStore'));
        } else {
            $openCloudDefinition->setFactoryService('sonata.media.adapter.filesystem.opencloud.connection');
            $openCloudDefinition->setFactoryMethod('ObjectStore');
        }

        $loader->load('validators.xml');
        $loader->load('serializer.xml');

        if (!in_array(strtolower($config['db_driver']), array('doctrine_orm', 'doctrine_mongodb', 'doctrine_phpcr'))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('SonataMediaBundle - Invalid db driver "%s".', $config['db_driver']));
        }

        $bundles = $container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');

        if (isset($bundles['FOSRestBundle']) && isset($bundles['NelmioApiDocBundle'])) {
            $loader->load(sprintf('api_form_%s.xml', $config['db_driver']));

            if ('doctrine_orm' == $config['db_driver']) {
                $loader->load('api_controllers.xml');
            }
        }

        if (isset($bundles['SonataNotificationBundle'])) {
            $loader->load('consumer.xml');
        }

        if (isset($bundles['SonataFormatterBundle'])) {
            $loader->load('formatter.xml');
        }

        if (isset($bundles['SonataBlockBundle'])) {
            $loader->load('block.xml');
        }

        if (isset($bundles['SonataSeoBundle'])) {
            $loader->load('seo_block.xml');
        }

        if (!isset($bundles['LiipImagineBundle'])) {
            $container->removeDefinition('sonata.media.thumbnail.liip_imagine');
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($config['default_context'], $config['contexts'])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('SonataMediaBundle - Invalid default context : %s, available : %s', $config['default_context'], json_encode(array_keys($config['contexts']))));
        }

        $loader->load(sprintf('%s.xml', $config['db_driver']));

        if (isset($bundles['SonataAdminBundle'])) {
            $loader->load(sprintf('%s_admin.xml', $config['db_driver']));
        }

        $this->configureFilesystemAdapter($container, $config);
        $this->configureCdnAdapter($container, $config);

        $pool = $container->getDefinition('sonata.media.pool');
        $pool->replaceArgument(0, $config['default_context']);

        // this shameless hack is done in order to have one clean configuration
        // for adding formats ....
        $pool->addMethodCall('__hack__', $config);

        $strategies = array();

        foreach ($config['contexts'] as $name => $settings) {
            $formats = array();

            foreach ($settings['formats'] as $format => $value) {
                $formats[$name.'_'.$format] = $value;
            }

            $strategies[] = $settings['download']['strategy'];
            $pool->addMethodCall('addContext', array($name, $settings['providers'], $formats, $settings['download']));
        }

        $container->setParameter('sonata.media.admin_format', $config['admin_format']);

        $strategies = array_unique($strategies);

        foreach ($strategies as $strategyId) {
            $pool->addMethodCall('addDownloadStrategy', array($strategyId, new Reference($strategyId)));
        }

        if ('doctrine_orm' == $config['db_driver']) {
            $this->registerDoctrineMapping($config);
        }

        $container->setParameter('sonata.media.resizer.simple.adapter.mode', $config['resizer']['simple']['mode']);
        $container->setParameter('sonata.media.resizer.square.adapter.mode', $config['resizer']['square']['mode']);

        $this->configureParameterClass($container, $config);
        $this->configureExtra($container, $config);
        $this->configureBuzz($container, $config);
        $this->configureProviders($container, $config);
        $this->configureAdapters($container, $config);
        $this->configureResizers($container, $config);
        $this->configureClassesToCompile();
    }
```

Normally this way is enough to my service, but in my case.

I would like to unload some xml loaded in original DependancyInjection.

for example

`$loader->load('media.xml');` is loaded in original one.

However I don't want to let this loaded.

I have two ideas

1. unload in my bundle
2. override(copy all script) original bundle and comment out.,but how can I override???

How can I do this ???

---

I want to remove yml for admin.
Sonata\MediaBundle\DependencyInjection\SonataMediaExtension

```
 if (isset($bundles['SonataAdminBundle'])) {
        $loader->load(sprintf('%s_admin.xml', $config['db_driver']));
    }
```

This quesion is related with 
[How to override xml under config directory to hide SonataMediaBundle and Classification setting from dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017286/how-to-override-xml-under-config-directory-to-hide-sonatamediabundle-and-classif)

---

Thanks to  @dbrumann comment, I decided to use CompilerPass.

I implemented

in Acme\AdminBundle\AcmeAdminBundle

```
namespace Acme\AdminBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Acme\AdminBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CustomPass;
//use  \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PassConfig;

class AcmeAdminBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new CustomPass());
    }
```

in CustomPass

```
namespace Acme\AdminBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class CustomPass implements CompilerPassInterface {
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        var_dump($container->getDefinitions());
        if ($container->hasDefinition('sonata.admin.arobject')) //I have arobject entity on dashboard
         {
           $container->removeDefinition('sonata.admin.arobject');
         }
    }
}
```

It looks like I have step forward. however this error happens.

```
[2/2] FileLoaderLoadException: You have requested a non-existent service "sonata.admin.arobject". Did you mean one of these: "sonata.admin.armarket", "sonata.admin.artracker", "sonata.admin.exporter", "sonata.admin.helper", "sonata.admin.placecat", "sonata.admin.pool", "sonata.admin.user"? in . (which is being imported from "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/arserver/app/config/routing.yml").
```

mysteriously `$container->hasDefinition('sonata.admin.arobject')` returns true, but,  `$container->removeDefinition('sonata.admin.arobject')` returns the error above.

This is my var_dump($container->getDefinitions()) [log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmeor8t2gvg0eqz/vardump.txt?dl=0)

---

Finally I found out there is two way to slove this problem.

1) Use CompilerPass

2) Load new service.xml

If you have trouble in removing mediabundle and classificationbundle from admin dashboard.

please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080760/sonata-media-bundle-remove-gallery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do sounds very dangerous. I'm not very familiar with SonataAdminBundle, but when the bundle is working with the provided services you will break it. Maybe you can extend the question with an explanation as to why you want to unload those services.

In the meantime you might want to checkout [CompilerPasses](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html). They run before the container is built and can alter it. You could call [removeDefinition()](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.html#method_removeDefinition) on the ContainerBuilder to get rid of the services. Instead of unloading the service you specifically remove the definitions you want to remove. Alternatively you could replace them with other services or alter them to your needs.

Comment: Thanks you, I updated the article. I am struggling with removing 'media bundle' from admin dashboard. I am trying to test some methods. Thanks to your reply I understand overriding whole DependancyInjection is not good way.

Comment: I maintain that CompilerPass seems a better choice for this. I'd have to look at how they are added to the dashboard, but I assume it's by tag. So you might be able to achieve your goal be removing the tag from the services.

Comment: Thank you very much, I decided to learn CompilerPass, However I bumped into the mysterious error like, $container->hasDefinition('sonata.admin.arobject') returns true, but $container->removeDefinition('sonata.admin.arobject'); removes error.

Comment: This is my  var_dump($container->getDefinitions()); https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmeor8t2gvg0eqz/vardump.txt?dl=0

Comment: @whitebear I updated my question. I hope editors will approve this change otherwise I might have to add it as a comment or another anwser

Comment: HI @Dbrumann I found this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080760/sonata-media-bundle-remove-gallery They discuss the same thing and show me the two way to slove 1.Use CompilerPass(as you mentioned) 2.load new services.xml in load function.

Comment: I have tried both and way 2 works. Then my problem is solved. however I am not sure why 1 is not working. I might study more how CompilerPass working. However you comment gives me the good insight to use symfony2  better. thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you found a way to make it work. My suggestion was to set priority for your CompilerPass and also instead of removing the id directly going via `$container->findTaggedServiceIds()`. It's an interesting edge case and I would like to know why it didn't work as well. Maybe I will try to reproduce it and dive deeper to see if it's a bug or something when I have some time to play around.